# How to retrieve a data in a Variable from EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

May be this is too trivial question.

I use C#, asp.net 4, EF4,

I have a page with a **DetailsView** control is connected with **EntityDataSource**. All is working.

In code behind I need to create a variable that will populate with data from **EntityDataSource**, lets imagine field **UserId**.

My questions: How to retrieve and use data from **EntityDataSource**?

Thanks guys. I am very beginners you advices are really important for me! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [DetailsView.DataKey Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.datakey.aspx) will help you

Comment: what about if is not an DataKey but another field like "FirstName" how to find out another record? thanks for now

Comment: What means "is not an DataKey"? You can use DataKey property always when you set correctly DataKeyNames property. See documentation about these two properties.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, maybe i pose the wrong question. I need to access arbitration data bounded with a DetailsView. In my case a use DataKey = AuthorId (int) but I need access the field FirstName (string) any ideas? thanks once again

Comment: DataKeyNames="AuthorId,FirstName"